# Сравнить переменную с датой в массиве

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Выбираю все по значению месяц и год из базы:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cal_db` WHERE MONTH(`date`) = $month AND YEAR(`date`) = $year");
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

А вот дальше не получается у меня сделать действие если дата из базы в поле DATE
соответствует переменной $datum

```
for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++)
{
    $datum = "$running_date-$list_day"; 
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if($datum == $value)
        {
            $calendar.= "ok";
        } else {
            $calendar.= 'no';
        }
    }
}
```

Примерно так.

Comment: Попробуйте так `strtotime($datum) == strtotime($value))`

Comment: А зачем это делать в php, если вы можете прямо в запросе проверить точную дату